# How indexing works in magento?

Tags: magento

I found that when i reindex from backend then magento create many additional table. what is the puprose of it?

for e.g. 
catalog_category_flat_store_1
catalog_product_flat_1
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flat tables are for the different stores in Magento. Each store will have its own flat table since each store can have different information for it.

The price index as far as I know is used to help speed up the category pages since it would be slower to use the actual price model for those pages.

For the most part all of the indexes in Magento are there to increase the overall speed of the system.